# Why does font css property remove bold weight?

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-size

I was tasked with removing unnecessary tags from computer-generated HTML that had a lot of useless tags (I only wanted to keep color/strong/em information). I came along something similar to this HTML:

```html
<b>
  <span style="FONT: 20pt &quot;Arial&quot;">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold
  </span>
</b>
```

For me (on chrome & firefox), it shows the `bold` text as bold and the `not bold` text as not bold, and I am confused as to why this is. In particular, this makes my task more complicated: I thought I could just remove the tags that do not have color/strong/em info, so change it to something like this:

```html
<b>
   <strong>bold</strong> not bold <strong>bold</strong> not bold
</b>
```

But now, all is bold instead of what it used to be.

I tried to find out what I could put in the `FONT` style to reproduce this behaviour:

Replacing `Arial` with `foo` kept the behaviour:

```html
<b>
  <span style="FONT: 20pt foo">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold <!-- not bold is actually not bold! 20pt is applied -->
  </span>
</b>
```

Switching the size and font changed the behaviour:

```html
<b>
  <span style="FONT: &quot;Arial&quot; 20pt">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold <!-- everything is bold. 20pt is _not_ applied -->
  </span>
</b>
```

Any of the two values on their own did nothing much:

```html
<b>
  <span style="FONT: &quot;Arial&quot;">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold <!-- everything is bold -->
  </span>
</b>
```

```html
<b>
  <span style="FONT: 20pt">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold <!-- everything is bold -->
  </span>
</b>
```

```html
<b>
  <span style="FONT: 20pt &quot;Arial&quot;">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold
</span>
</b>

<div>Replacing `Arial` with `foo` kept the behaviour:</div>

<b>
  <span style="FONT: 20pt foo">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold
<!-- not bold is actually not bold! 20pt is applied -->
</span>
</b>

<div>Switching the size and font changed the behaviour:</div>

<b>
  <span style="FONT: &quot;Arial&quot; 20pt">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold
<!-- everything is bold. 20pt is _not_ applied -->
</span>
</b>


<div>Any of the two values on their own did nothing much:</div>

<b>
  <span style="FONT: &quot;Arial&quot;">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold
<!-- everything is bold -->
</span>
</b>

<b>
  <span style="FONT: 20pt">
    <strong>bold</strong> not bold <b>bold</b> not bold
<!-- everything is bold -->
</span>
</b>
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour, or at least tell me what styles I should look for that cancel outer styles?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong  Please review the actual tag definition to help yourself understand the WHY here.

Comment: Added a snippet with the HTML to better visualize here

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to my question, on the [font css property documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font). It states:

> As with any shorthand property, any individual value that is not
> specified **is set to its corresponding initial value** (possibly
> overriding values previously set using non-shorthand properties).
> Though not directly settable by font, the longhands font-size-adjust
> and font-kerning are also reset to their initial values.

(My emphasis)

And a bit further down:

> Initial value as each of the properties of the shorthand:
>
> - font-style: normal
> - font-variant: normal
> - font-weight: normal
> - font-stretch: normal
> - font-size: medium
> - line-height: normal
> - font-family: depends on user agent

So setting `font: 20pt arial` is equivalent to setting `font-style: normal;font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-size: 20pt;line-height: normal;font-family: arial`

In particular, the `font-weight` is reset from `bold` (or whatever it was) to `normal`.

So to solve my underlying question, I should look for `font` tags that do not specify the weight.

P.S. The reason that `font: arial 20pt` did *not* have this behaviour is because this is not an allowed value for `font`, so it is ignored:

> If font is specified as a shorthand for several font-related properties, then:
>
> - it must include values for: `<font-size>` `<font-family>`
> - `font-style`, `font-variant` and `font-weight` must precede `font-size`
> - `font-family` must be the last value specified.

And in `font: arial 20pt` the font-family is not the last value specified.

Comment: Spot on. The only thing to watch out for is that certain reserved words are valid values for the font shorthand even without a font-size. So `font: arial` is invalid and has no effect, but `font: caption` is valid and will reset the font-weight value.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts depend on your actual browser and actual font. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

> Fonts have a particular weight which corresponds to one of the numbers
> in Common weight name mapping. However some fonts, called variable
> fonts, can support a range of weights with a more or less fine
> granularity, and this can give the designer a much closer degree of
> control over the chosen weight.

WHICH of the copyrighted or not fonts do you have? Depends.  Browser, computer, CSS etc. but we cannot tell here.
Always specify a fallback (`sans-serif` in this case)  This can all get a bit "tricky".

Bottom line: put all this in CSS and use classes so you can actually control it best and less HTML overall when you decide to change things Like `pt` is not normally great for visual but is for printed but not used much in modern HTML as a size.  Now if you decide to change the size you have a lot of places to change it but if in CSS only one.

Now for some examples: (not all inclusive of the topic by any means)

```css
.container {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 1em;
}

.container .fonty {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
}

.heavy-one {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.heavy-two {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="fonty">
    <span class="heavy-one">bold</span> not bold <span class="heavy-two">bolder</span> not bold
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="fonty heavy-container">
    <span class="heavy-one">bold</span> not bold <span class="heavy-two">bolder</span> not bold
  </span>
</div>
<p>One with style in tags: (don't do this)
  <span>
  <span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20pt;  font-family: 'arial', 'Arial', sans-serif;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span> not bold <span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span> not bold</span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>Second with style in tags: (don't do this, bolder not great IMHO as it is one step heavier)</p>
<span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20pt;  font-family: 'arial', 'Arial', sans-serif;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span> not bold <span style="font-weight: bolder;">bold</span> not bold</span>

<p>Third with style in tags and &lt;strong&gt;: (don't do this) This also shows multiple similar font families and the fallback to &quot;sans-serif&quot; you should always include</p>
<span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20pt;  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;"><strong>bold</strong> not bold <strong>bold</strong> not bold</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. However, I do not want to specify a fallback, I do not want to specify the font at all. I just want to remove font-information without removing other information.

Comment: Different question than what you asked entirely.

Comment: Please read my answer below and the question carefully: If I set "font: 20pt sans-serif", the "font-weight" is set to "normal" and my question is _why_ this happens (And the answer to that question is in my answer below). I never asked about how to set specific fonts or what to do if fonts are missing from my system. Nevertheless I am grateful for your effort in helping me with these issues.

Comment: Remove "tag" typically means removing elements; so perhaps your question needed clarification when you really wanted to remove style attribute values.

Comment: Well, when I remove a tag, all style attribute values on that tag are also removed.

Comment: None of your "results" show a removal of the span which had the font - so I can now comfortably downvote your question as asked.  Not really here to debate your question quality but only answer it as best we can given how you asked it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249699/discussion-between-student91-and-mark-schultheiss).

Comment: Rolled back the edit that broke the functional snippet anther user made.